# Integrating LinkedIn with android

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I have developed an application for social and I want integrating Facebook,LinkedIn, Google, so I know I how to integrate Facebook to the android but I am little confuse about LinkedIn so please provide me some Tutorial for integrate LinkedIn to the android

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Go to this [http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/457153/How-to-integrate-Facebook-Twitter-Linkedin-in-Andr](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/457153/How-to-integrate-Facebook-Twitter-Linkedin-in-Andr)

Comment: i want to contact list of user, is it possible in LinkedIn like Facebook..?

Comment: @SpringBreaker: the domain is changed now check it at here:
http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2013/05/linkedin-integration-in-android.html

Answer (score 1):

please check my library: https://github.com/antonkrasov/AndroidSocialNetworks

It allows you simple integration with Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter and Google Plus.
All what you need is instantiate SocialNetworkManager and add it to your FragmentManager.

```
mSocialNetworkManager = (SocialNetworkManager) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SOCIAL_NETWORK_TAG);

if (mSocialNetworkManager == null) {
    mSocialNetworkManager = SocialNetworkManager.Builder.from(getActivity())
            .twitter(<< TWITTER  API TOKEN  >>, << TWITTER  API SECRET  >>)
            .linkedIn(<< LINKED_IN  API TOKEN  >>, << LINKED_IN API TOKEN  >>, "r_basicprofile+rw_nus+r_network+w_messages")
            .facebook()
            .googlePlus()
            .build();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(mSocialNetworkManager, SOCIAL_NETWORK_TAG).commit();
}
```

Now you are able to execute requests, like: login, addFriend (send connection request for LinedIn), postMessage, postPhoto, getProfile...

```
mSocialNetworkManager.getTwitterSocialNetwork().requestLogin(new OnLoginCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoginSuccess(int socialNetworkID) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int socialNetworkID, String requestID, String errorMessage, Object data) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn has no concept `friend` as Facebook. It has `connection`. Other apps could retrieve only 1st degree connections. More here: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api